# How to prevent notification sounds when I am *using* the phone?

Tags: notifications

I wish to not hear notification sounds when I am using the phone. When I am reading an e-book, or news article and the notification sound disrupts the process.

I would like to hear the notification sounds when I am away, but only notification icons on the notification bar when I am actively using the phone.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I think may be by using Tasker u can do this by creating different user profiles and activating them when u away

Comment: [Tasker](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/tasker/info) is a good pointer here (and indeed can do that, with the context "app › (select your reading apps)" and turning off notification sound in "settings › sound"), but it doesn't come for free. For alternatives, also take a look at our [automation tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/automation/info). And of course check the questions using those tags :)